# Why the difference in outputs in different cores?

Tags: evaluation

Executing the code

```
r = RegionIntersection[Region[Ball[3]],  Region[Ball[{1/2, 1/3, 5/6}, 1]]];
Region[r]
```

in version 11.3.0.0 on Windows 10 32-bit, I don't obtain any plot, only unclear output with "Embedding dimension: 3". However, this code works  on Wolfram Cloud (see [screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ausie1mhn9iu3y/screen2.docx?dl=0) ) and on 64- bit Windows (as I was kindly informed by Technical Support [CASE:4195740] ).

Addition. In view of the above I can execute

```
Volume[r]
```

on neither my comp nor  the cloud.

Addition 2. The reinstallation of Mathematica on my comp solved the problem. I am grateful to Duncan Pettengill for his well-meaning and professional attitude to my case.

Comment: Please change your title to be an *informative* one... one that actually describes the core issues in your problem.

Comment: @David G. Stork: The title was changed up to your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Only use [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) wrappers to view regions:

```
r = RegionIntersection[Ball[3], Ball[{1/2, 1/3, 5/6}, 1]];
Region[r]
```

[image]

I don't have 32-bit Windows, so this may not help you.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed typo (see the screen) before your edit. This is not the only case when the code works in 64-bit version, but does not work in 32-bit version. I will be waiting for a serious answer.